# How can i fill this matrix (then generalize it to an 3D-array) whit a loop and using conditions too? in R

Tags: r, loops, matrix, conditional-statements, fill

I just want to fill this matrix, I know this is a very easy problem, but I'm not good at all.
I won't use these numbers in the matrix.
I had tried with for loop, but the problem is this loop only shows the last iteration.
I repeat, I don't want the numbers from 1 to 9.
I have this:

```
(mat<-matrix(0, nrow = 3, ncol = 3))
for (i in 1:3) {
  for (j in 1:3) {
    if (j==1 & i==1) {
      mat[i,j]=6
    } else if (j==1 & i==2) {
      mat[i,j]=7
    } else if (j==1 & i==3) {
      mat[i,j]=8
    }
  }
}
```

I want a code whithout put the conditions `& i==1, & i==2, & i==3`.
I want to make another variable `k` from 1 to 3. I tried this, but the loop only show me the value in 3.
Thank you so much.

Edit: I'm going to show you an example abou I want to solve. You will see that's about the same problem. I have the next data frame:

```
base2<-c(  20, 15, 17, 23, 19, 21, 16, 22, 18)
base2.1<-c( 6,  5,  3,  4,  1,  7,  2,  9,  8)
base3<-data.frame(base2,base2.1)
names(base3)=c("age","mean")

base3
```

I want to fill a vector `vec` where `vec[1]=5` (because as you can see,`age=15`), `vec[2]=2` (because ,`age=16`) and so on, so on.

I have tried this just for the first element:

```
(vec<-c(rep(0,length(base3$mean))))

for (i in 1:length(base3$mean)) {
  if (base3$age[i]==15) {
    vec[1]=base3$mean[which(base3$age==15)]
      } 
}
vec
```

Of course, I don't want to put number 1 on this part of the loop: `vec[1]=base3$mean[which(base3$age==15)`

If I want to fill the entire vector, I have this:

```
for (i in 1:length(base3$mean)) {
  for (j in sort(base3$age)) {
vec[i]=base3$mean[which(base3$age==j)]  
 }
}
vec
```

But the foor loop only show me the last iteration:

```
# [1] 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4
```

I want the next result:

```
[1] 5 2 3 8 1 6 7 9 4
```

Comment: So instead of the numbers `6, 7, 8` you want the numbers in the variable `k`?

Comment: Provide a desired output please.

Comment: @RuiBarradas please, read my Edit.

Comment: @Adamm I've put the output I want. Please, read my edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is simply to `order` vector `age` and use the index returned to index vector `mean`.

```
i <- order(base3$age)
vec <- base3$mean[i]

vec
#[1] 5 2 3 8 1 6 7 9 4
```

See `help("order")`, and the difference to `sort`.
A one-liner is

```
vec <- base3$mean[order(base3$age)]
```

Comment: That's perfect! Thanks.
If I'd like to use a for loop or any function of  "apply()" family, how can I solve the problem? (I'll do this in a very big dataset. Thank you, master!

Comment: @Edgorelml You would have to write a sort routine that keeps the data in the original order and sorts indices into the vector, and in the end returns the indices. If the data set is very big, you'd better stick to R's sorter routines.